# Code igniter 2.2.6 404 error on live server

Tags: codeigniter

I have an website with CI 2.2.6 with two apps :

- /frontend
- /admin
- /system

I set this in both application config/config.php

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['uri_protocol']    = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in admin/index.php

```
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../admin';
```

in admin/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin|images|assets|favicon\.ico|rss\.xml|sitemap\.xml|BingSiteAuth\.xml|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I can access to all frontend page that is the default application. But when I go to /admin i can see the admin default layout but its always the default 404 error controller that is loaded whatever the link I clicked on.

This is working on localhost (php 5.5.26) but not on live server (php 5.5.9).

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin|images|assets|favicon\.ico|rss\.xml|sitemap\.xml|BingSiteAuth\.xml|robots\.txt)

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I get the message "Directory access is forbidden." so that the index.html that is loaded...(but other pages works when I type the url) Any idea ?

Comment: remove index.html or add DirectoryIndex index.php to htaccess file